# Blur on clear all values with React-Select

Tags: react-select

Does anyone know how to blur the element after the clear all values has been clicked?

There isn't a prop that allows me to capture the clear all click except for the onChange.

The clear all method calls focus and overrides my blur unless I timeout for 600+ seconds and then call blur...but there has to be a better way.

thanks

Comment: more context would be useful, maybe you can use preventDefault  to stop event from passing when clearall is called ?

Comment: That's mainly my issue, there doesn't seem to be an api that let's me tap into the clearall method.
    From what I can tell the flow is this:
    1. Clear all clicked
    2. OnChange triggered (this prop I have access to, thus where I can call blur)
    3. ClearAll method called (no access to this method)
    4. ClearAll calls focus.

Comment: could you provide code snippet ?